# I have stuck with making remove()

Tags: java, linked-list

Hi I'm trying to make remove method. But I don't know How to make this right. Here is my code.

This is LinkedList.java from Algorithm fourth edition.

```
/**
 * <i>Algorithms, 4th Edition</i> by Robert Sedgewick and Kevin 
 * Wayne.
 * @author Robert Sedgewick
 * @author Kevin Wayne
 */
public class LinkedQueue<Item> implements Iterable<Item> {
     private int N;         // number of elements on queue
   private Node first;    // beginning of queue
       private Node last;     // end of queue

// helper linked list class
private class Node {
    private Item item;
      private Node next;
 }

 /**
 * Initializes an empty queue.
 */
 public LinkedQueue() {
    first = null;
    last  = null;
    N = 0;
    assert check();
}

/**
 * Is this queue empty?
 * @return true if this queue is empty; false otherwise
 */
public boolean isEmpty() {
    return first == null;
}

/**
 * Returns the number of items in this queue.
 * @return the number of items in this queue
 */
public int size() {
    return N;     
}

/**
 * Returns the item least recently added to this queue.
 * @return the item least recently added to this queue
 * @throws java.util.NoSuchElementException if this queue is empty
 */
public Item peek() {
    if (isEmpty()) throw new NoSuchElementException("Queue underflow");
    return first.item;
}

/**
 * Adds the item to this queue.
 * @param item the item to add
 */
public void enqueue(Item item) {
    Node oldlast = last;
    last = new Node();
    last.item = item;
    last.next = null;
    if (isEmpty()) first = last;
    else           oldlast.next = last;
    N++;
    assert check();
}

/**
 * Removes and returns the item on this queue that was least recently added.
 * @return the item on this queue that was least recently added
 * @throws java.util.NoSuchElementException if this queue is empty
 */
public Item dequeue() {
    if (isEmpty()) throw new NoSuchElementException("Queue underflow");
    Item item = first.item;
    first = first.next;
    N--;
    if (isEmpty()) last = null;   // to avoid loitering
    assert check();
    return item;
}

/**
 * Returns a string representation of this queue.
 * @return the sequence of items in FIFO order, separated by spaces
 */
public String toString() {
    StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
    for (Item item : this)
        s.append(item + " ");
    return s.toString();
} 

// check internal invariants
private boolean check() {
    if (N == 0) {
        if (first != null) return false;
        if (last  != null) return false;
    }
    else if (N == 1) {
        if (first == null || last == null) return false;
        if (first != last)                 return false;
        if (first.next != null)            return false;
    }
    else {
        if (first == last)      return false;
        if (first.next == null) return false;
        if (last.next  != null) return false;

        // check internal consistency of instance variable N
        int numberOfNodes = 0;
        for (Node x = first; x != null; x = x.next) {
           numberOfNodes++;
        }
        if (numberOfNodes != N) return false;

        // check internal consistency of instance variable last
        Node lastNode = first;
        while (lastNode.next != null) {
           lastNode = lastNode.next;
        }
        if (last != lastNode) return false;
    }

    return true;
}
//working properly
void reverseBystack(){
    Stack<Item> s = new Stack<>();
    Item item;
    while (isEmpty() != true){
        item = dequeue();
        s.push(item);
    }
    while(s.isEmpty() != true){
        item = s.pop();
        enqueue(item);
    }


}
//working properly.
 void reverseBylink() {
    Node prev = null;
    Node current = this.first;
    Node next = null;
    Node temp = null;
    while (current != null) {
        next = current.next;
        current.next = prev;
        prev = current;
        current = next;
    }
    temp =first;
    first = last;
    last = temp;

 }


    //How to do this...;<..
int remove(Item item) {
    Node cur = this.first;
    while (cur !=null) {

        if (cur.item.equals(item)) {
            item  = dequeue();
        }

        cur = cur.next;
        N++;

    }

 return 0;
}


/**
 * Returns an iterator that iterates over the items in this queue in FIFO order.
 * @return an iterator that iterates over the items in this queue in FIFO order
 */
public Iterator<Item> iterator()  {
    return new ListIterator();  
}

// an iterator, doesn't implement remove() since it's optional
private class ListIterator implements Iterator<Item> {
    private Node current = first;

    public boolean hasNext()  { return current != null;                     }
    public void remove()      { throw new UnsupportedOperationException();  }

    public Item next() {
        if (!hasNext()) throw new NoSuchElementException();
        Item item = current.item;
        current = current.next; 
        return item;
    }
}
```

Unit tests

```
/**
 * Unit tests the <tt>LinkedQueue</tt> data type.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    LinkedQueue<String> q = new LinkedQueue<String>();

   /* Working properly for reverseByStack.
    q.enqueue("a");
    q.enqueue("b");
    q.enqueue("c");
    q.enqueue("a");
    q.enqueue("b");
    q.enqueue("d");
    q.enqueue("b");
    q.enqueue("abba");
    q.enqueue("a");
    q.enqueue("z");
    q.enqueue("a");
    q.reverseBystack();
    System.out.println(q);
    StdOut.println("(" + q.size() + " left on queue)");
    */


    /*Move on to next, working properly
    q.enqueue("a");
    q.enqueue("b");
    q.enqueue("c");
    q.enqueue("a");
    q.enqueue("b");
    q.enqueue("d");
    q.enqueue("b");
    q.enqueue("abba");
    q.enqueue("a");
    q.enqueue("z");
    q.enqueue("a");
    q.reverseBylink();
    System.out.println(q);
    StdOut.println("(" + q.size() + "left on queue)");*/

    q.enqueue("a");
    q.enqueue("b");
    q.enqueue("c");
    q.enqueue("a");
    q.enqueue("b");
    q.enqueue("d");
    q.enqueue("b");
    q.enqueue("abba");
    q.enqueue("a");
    q.enqueue("z");
    q.enqueue("a");
    System.out.println(q);
    System.out.println("Remove some of elements. and use reverseByLink");


    q.remove("a");
    q.remove("f");
    q.remove("c");

    System.out.println(q);
}
```

Output.

```
a b c a b d b abba a z a
```

Remove some of elements. and use reverseByLink

```
a b d b abba a z a
```

I don't know why String a is not removed and after abba.

Comment: Please use `{` and `}` around **all** blocks. It will make your life easier, and anyone reading/editing your code.

Answer (score 1):

```
int remove(Item item) {
    if(this.first == null)
        return 0;

    if(this.first == item) {
        // remove root item
        Node node = this.first.next;
        this.first.next = null;
        this.first = node;
        return 1;
    }

    Node prv = this.first;

    while (prv.next != item)
        prv = prv.next;

    // item was not found
    if(prv == null)
        return 0;

    Node node = prv.next.next;
    prv.next.next = null;
    prv.next = node;

    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly sure this method is wrong:

```
int remove(Item item) {
    Node cur = this.first;
    while (cur !=null) {

        if (cur.item.equals(item)) {
            item  = dequeue();
        }

        cur = cur.next;
        N++;

    }

 return 0;
}
```

Your `dequeue` method pops the front of the list. But the item you're removing might not be the front of the list.

I didn't look for more problems.

This is standard linked list stuff. Some of your textbooks should have algorithms for this. But basically, you need to keep track of the last pointer you used. Let's say you have `lastPtr` and `currentPtr`, and you determine that `currentPtr` needs to go.

Then `lastPtr.next = currentPtr.next`

It's more interesting if you're at the head. You need to recognize that and instead do `first.next = currentPtr.next`.

Answer (score 0):

dequeue() methods is popping out items from the front , but to remove all the occurrences of any string , you need to modify your remove() method to -

```
void remove(Item item) {
        Node cur = this.first;
        Node prev = null;
        if(this.first.item.equals(item)){
            item = dequeue();
            cur = this.first;
        }
        while (cur != null) {

           /* if (cur.item.equals(item)) {
                item = dequeue();
            }*/

           while(cur != null && !cur.item.equals(item)) {
               prev = cur;
               cur = cur.next;
           }

           if(cur == null)
               return;
           prev.next = cur.next;
           cur = prev.next;
        }

        return ;

    }
```